# What are Global Constraints in constraint programming?

Tags: constraints, constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-optimizer

I see that ORTools and CpOptimizer both use global constraints. I know it speeds up the search a lot, but what does it actually do? Like what is the difference between me using (1) or (2) below;

Example for the AllDifferent constraint:

1) `x1 != x2, x2 != x3, x1 != x3`

and

2) `AllDifferent(x1, x2, x3)`

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. We rebuild the all-different cliques. Still, it will be faster for presolve if you use the AllDifferent formulation.

Now, the CP-SAT is a based on a SAT solver, and prefers Boolean variables.
In your case, you can try removing integer variables, and use arrays of Boolean variables with a `sum (boolvars) <= 1`.